# judge if the content in the textbox changes

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a C# WPF question. I need to set a trigger event to examine that if the content in a textbox has been changed. No matter a user adds or deletes any character in the textbox, I can get this as a trigger event. How to do this? Thanks.

Comment: @ASh, OP say "trigger event" not *binding*, nor *setter*.

Comment: @Sinatr, my telepathic-debug co-processor is malfunctioning and may return false-positives. Glad that your is ok and and you have enough energy to write code on demand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XAML :

```
<TextBox TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

Code Behind :

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
}
```

'TextBox_TextChanged' this event will get triggered whenever user will change the text inside the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in past to animate text changes:

```
<TextBox Text="123">
    <TextBox.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.TextChanged">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     To="0"
                                     Duration="0:0:.5" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TextBox.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```